# Is the appetizer of a three-course meal always a salad?

Tags: traditional

A [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/three-course-meal) says

> A three-course meal in a local restaurant will not cost more than $10.
>   The three-course meal includes an **appetizer**, entrée, and dessert.
>   The first course of the three-course meal is a **salad**.

It seems to indicate the appetizer of a three-course meal is always a salad, is it true? Is it true just in the U.S.?

Answer (score 7):

The three sentences you quote are *example usage* of the phrase, and not part of the definition. These are simply sentences that demonstrate usage of the defined phrase, but are not part of the definition.

The definition, which is always true, is this part:

> A three-course meal is a meal that consists of three parts served one after the other.

Other statements that could be true of a three-course meal:

- A three-course meal can cost significantly more than $10.
- The three-course meal could include courses of a salami, a pasta, and a meat.
- The last course of a three-course meal could be a salad

Comment: Yah, jeez, here when restaurants have a three-course meal for $33 they advertise it as a special.

Answer (score 2):

Three courses can be absolutely anything, the first course could be a salad, cold meats or cheeses, soup or something cooked - there are way too many options to list. A **typical** 3 course meal in the US would have the starter/appetizer be a small savory dish, followed by the entree, then a dessert. But it doesn't have to follow that format.

As for cost, ten bucks is cheap, it's pretty unlikely you'd ever get a 3 course meal for that price. Maybe in the 80s.